# R Error: unknown input format

Tags: r, import, transformation

```
NEI <- readRDS(unz(tf, filename = "summarySCC_PM25.rds", open = "", encoding = getOption("encoding")))
```

*Variable tf* is a **temporary** file with a very specific location saved on the hard drive. It is my understanding that the format for [unz()](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/connections.html) is:

```
unz(description, filename, open = "", encoding = getOption("encoding"))
```

As I read the documentation, I am interpreting that my application of the code is accurate as that:

1. description is a specific zip file destination, which outputs in *var tf* as c://...//345du.zip
2. filename is summarySCC_PM25.rds, which is the file to be extracted *from tf*
3. open is already established in the var so black should be fine
4. encoding labels the language type.

Within the context of the code above, I receive "Error: unknown input format" from R 3.1.1. I need clarification on what might be happening as that I interpret my code to be the same as:

```
NEI <- readRDS("summarySCC_PM25.rds")
```

Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: Could you provide an example file to be read in and to make this reproducible? I have no trouble using `readRDS` so I can't reproduce your error to help you.

Comment: I am not sure. The way the code works is that it: 1) creates a temporary directory 2) creates a temporary file 3) downloads the file from a URL into the temporary file 4) the code calls t5e temporary file 5) to this above

Comment: I think I found your file by doing a Google search on the name. Is this the same data? https://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140617173447-5576436-explore-n-analyze-data-assignment-2

Comment: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/exdata%2Fdata%2FNEI_data.zip

Comment: though it don't think that helps since R downloads the file successfully

Comment: that zip file becomes converted to "c://...//345du.zip" in a temporary file and directory. The problem might be the double forward slashes

Comment: unzip() seems to work. it is just odd that this route didn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Avoid unz() and use unzip(withanindex) since the temp file is a moving target

Answer (score 1):

I found your data online so that I can read your file. It was available from here:

https://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140617173447-5576436-explore-n-analyze-data-assignment-2

```
> unzip("C:\\Users\\jmiller\\Downloads\\exdata_data_NEI_data.zip")
> NEI <- readRDS("summarySCC_PM25.rds")
> dim(NEI)
[1] 6497651       6
> colnames(NEI)
[1] "fips"      "SCC"       "Pollutant" "Emissions" "type"      "year"
```

Comment: tried this code and in my temporary file scenario, R crashed. twice.

Comment: thank you for the assist. it appears that unz() doesn't work in temporary zip file conditions.