# Reading an RDS file within a zip file without extracting to disk

Tags: r, import, zip

Is there a reason I can't read a RDS file from within a zip file directly, without having to unzip it to a temp file on disk first?

Let's say this is the zip file:

```
saveRDS(cars, "cars.rds")
saveRDS(iris, "iris.rds")
write.csv(iris, "iris.csv")
zip("datasets.zip", c("cars.rds", "iris.rds", "iris.csv"))
file.remove("cars.rds", "iris.rds", "iris.csv")
```

For the csv file, I could read it directly like this:

```
iris2 <- read.csv(unz("datasets.zip", "iris.csv"))
```

However, I don't understand why I can't use `unz()` directly with `readRDS()`:

```
iris3 <- readRDS(unz("datasets.zip", "iris.rds"))
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error: unknown input format
```

I'd also like to understand why this happens. I'm aware that I could do the following, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772964/r-error-unknown-input-format):

```
path <- unzip("datasets.zip", "iris.rds")
iris4 <- readRDS(path)
file.remove(path)
```

This doesn't seem as efficient, though, and I need to do it frequently for a really large number of files, so I/O inefficiencies matter. Is there any workaround to read the rds file without extracting it to disk?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was a little tricky to track down until I read the body of `readRDS()`. What it seems you need to do is

1. Open a connection to the `.zip` archive and the file inside it with `unz()`
2. Apply GZIP decompression to this connection using `gzcon()`
3. And finally pass this decompressed connection to `readRDS()`.

Here's an example to illustrate using the following serialised matrix `mat` inside a zip archive `matrix.zip`

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, ncol = 3)
saveRDS(mat, "matrix.rds")
zip("matrix.zip", "matrix.rds")
```

Open a connection to `matrix.zip`

```
con <- unz("matrix.zip", filename = "matrix.rds")
```

Now, using `gzcon()`, apply GZIP decompression to this connection

```
con2 <- gzcon(con)
```

Finally, read from the connection

```
mat2 <- readRDS(con2)
```

In full we have

```
con <- unz("matrix.zip", filename = "matrix.rds")
con2 <- gzcon(con)
mat2 <- readRDS(con2)
close(con2)
```

This gives

```
> con <- unz("matrix.zip", filename = "matrix.rds")
> con2 <- gzcon(con)
> mat2 <- readRDS(con2)
> close(con2)
> mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> all.equal(mat, mat2)
[1] TRUE
```

#### Why?

Why you have to go through this convoluted extra step is (I think) described in `?readRDS`:

> Compression is handled by the connection opened when `file` is a
>        file name, so is only possible when `file` is a connection if
>        handled by the connection.  So e.g. `url` connections will need to
>        be wrapped in a call to `gzcon`.

And if you look at the internals of `readRDS()` we see:

```
> readRDS
function (file, refhook = NULL) 
{
    if (is.character(file)) {
        con <- gzfile(file, "rb")
        on.exit(close(con))
    }
    else if (inherits(file, "connection")) 
        con <- file
    else stop("bad 'file' argument")
    .Internal(unserializeFromConn(con, refhook))
}
<bytecode: 0x2841998>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

If `file` is a character string for the file name, the object is decompressed using `gzile()` to create the connection to the `.rds` we want to read. Notice that if you pass a connection as `file`, as you want to do, at no point has R decompressed the connection. `file` is just assigned to `con` and then passed to the internal function `unserializeFromConn`. Hence wrapping `gzcon()` around the connection created by `unz` works.

Basically, when `unserializeFromConn` reads from a connection it expects it to be decompressed but that decompression only happen automagically when you pass `readRDS()` a filename, not a connection.

Comment: This is great, makes sense! And it works for my original example: `iris3 <- readRDS(gzcon(unz("datasets.zip", "iris.rds")))`.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for `readRDS()` is

```
saveRDS(object, file = "", ascii = FALSE, version = NULL,
    compress = TRUE, refhook = NULL)
```

but, distressingly, there is nothing in the signature for `readRDS`. Yet, when you read the documentation for `readRDS` you get this little gem

```
## or examine the object via a connection, which will be opened as needed.
con <- gzfile("women.rds")
readRDS(con)
close(con)
```

and also

```
## Less convenient ways to restore the object
## which demonstrate compatibility with unserialize()
con <- gzfile("women.rds", "rb")
identical(unserialize(con), women)
close(con)
con <- gzfile("women.rds", "rb")
wm <- readBin(con, "raw", n = 1e4) # size is a guess
close(con)
identical(unserialize(wm), women)
```

The other thing to consider is what your gains are going to be using compression on an RDS object at all. Consider

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(1e7), ncol=10)
saveRDS(X, file = "X.rds")
system("cp X.rds XZ.rds")
system("gzip XZ.rds")
uncomp <- file.info("X.rds")$size
comp <- file.info("XZ.rds.gz")$size
savings <- (1 - comp/uncomp)
# [1] -0.00030541
```

so, for a not atypical example, compressing the RDS object is costing us space.

Comment: Yes, you can access a rds file through `gzfile` directly, but not if the rds is with a zip file, which is my issue. I'm also aware that there might be a small loss of disk space from zipping together xz-compressed rds files, unfortunately this is how I'm receiving the data.

Comment: Ahh, that is unfortunate. Simply trying to be helpful. I, too, have had to deal with presented data that is not in the optimal format. Good luck!